# Django. Statics not loading

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

Hello I am using Django 1.8.7 and I have problems with my static, apparently they are not loaded, and the request for the css seems to go the right path.

This is my `settings.py` file:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR + '/templates/'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR + 'static', PROJECT_PATH + 'static')
```

This is my project structure:

```
tree -I *pyc
.
├── db.sqlite3
├── django_vuldrone
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── mainapp
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── css
│   │       └── tem.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── mainapp
│   │       └── tem.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── manage.py
├── static
│   └── css
│       └── nano.css
└── templates
    └── base.html
```

I have a `base.html` outside the `mainapp` directory, and this is loaded perfectly in my `tem.html`, the problem are the `tem.css` and `nano.css` files, which are not loaded.

This is how my `base.html` looks like:

```
{% load staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/nano.css' %}" >
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My helpful timestamp site</h1>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %} 
    <h1>Thanks for visiting my site.</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my `tem.html` file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/tem.css' %}" >

{% block title %}The current time{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% for vulnerability in vulnerabilities %}

    <p>{{ vulnerability.cve }}</p>

{% endfor %}

{% for product in products %}

    <h1>{{ product.vendor }}</h1>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to consider when using django static files finders:

- It will look for a static/ folder on every installed app you have. So you create a app_name/static/app_name in order to do {% static app_name/css/xxx.css %} in your templates.
- If you have a static/ folder in your root project folder (because you want to import these statics in your templates this way {% static css/bootstrap.css %}, i. e. you want to store here your global static files, etc.), you have to add this folder by hand with the STATICFILES_DIRS settings variable.

Your problem is your static dirs are making conflict between them, and django does not know which one do you want to import when you are doing {% static css/whatever.css %}

So move your mainapp/static/css/tem.css to mainapp/static/mainapp/css/tem.css and change your static import to {% static mainapp/css/tem.css %}. If you want to import from your global static files folder do {% static /css/nano.css %}

Comment: Yeah, you were right dude, thank you very much. I have one question: Do you know why the href is: `static/mainapp/css/tem.css` instead of `../../static/mainapp/css/tem.css` It is like the real location of the .html is the name of the app, not the "visible" location. The same for the base template I have under my root directory, to get to the css, the url is `static/css/nano.css` instead of `../../static/css/nano.css`. Thank you dude

Answer (score 2):

I think the leading slash on the pathname is the problem.

Do this instead:

```
{% static 'css/tem.css' %}
```

Comment: I thought you were going to be right but I tried it and..... no =(. I get the same message: `[22/Dec/2015 16:37:54] "GET /static/css/nano.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1649`. And that is in fact the right path.

Comment: If you try to get that URL directly in your browser, does it work?

Comment: I get a `404` not found but I'm not sure if this is supposed to work given my `urls.py` config

Comment: are we talking about runserver with debug True or production ? also BASE_DIR + 'static' is pointing to the correct path in you file system ?

Comment: Now it is partially solved, I tried this: `STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,"static"))
` And I load the `css` in the root directory, but no the one placed in `mainapp/static/mainapp` I am not sure if the `PROJECT_PATH` is wrong.

Comment: I don't know why! It all seems to be right, I have added these two lines: `print "base dir path", BASE_DIR

print "project path", PROJECT_PATH` in my `settings.py` file and I get the following: `python manage.py runserver
base dir path /root/Documents/Projects/django_vuldrone
project path /root/Documents/Projects/django_vuldrone/django_vuldrone` which make sense because the `settings.py` file is inside `django-vuldrone/django-vuldrone`.
Any idea¿?